# Click "chat" in a particular site in HTTPS: all chatrooms of all sites appear

Tags: bug, chat, top-bar, ssl

Each site used to have its own chat room(s), even beta sites.

Now on https://security.stackexchange.com and https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com when I open the upper left menu and click "chat", I am sent to:

https://chat.stackexchange.com

Is it a new policy, or a bug, or my fault?

See the URL in the lower left when I hover my mouse on "chat":

[image: chat]

When I click on it, it sends me to a page where 27 pages of chatrooms appear, with entertaining names such as "Maid Café" or "The Frying Pan", and finding which ones are about information security is a big challenge.

Comment: I also go to chat.se, but it only shows rooms from the site i was on.

Comment: @Scimonster: Try again in HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that when using https, the Referer header is not being sent to the server, thus https://chat.stackexchange.com/ can't know where you came from, and won't show the proper rooms.

If you're browsing the non-secure site e.g. https://security.stackexchange.com/ it's working fine.

This is by design behavior of browsers, according to this: [Is HTTP header Referer sent when going to a http page from a https page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361705/is-http-header-referer-sent-when-going-to-a-http-page-from-a-https-page)

So, we need to ask the team to change the code so that a querystring parameter will be sent, and not rely on the Referer anymore, if we want this to work properly in https.

Comment: +1 You are right! I believe this should be considered a bug. Might be hard to fix, but still a bug.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul the bug is in the initial logic relying on referer. The original intention is working just fine, so I doubt it can be considered a bug. :/

Comment: I agree with you that relying on referer is a bug. The whole thing has to be refactored, as HTTP becomes less and less tolerated.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul agree, however turns out it's a dupe. Closed now, feel free to upvote the original report.